# how I could compile kotlin tornadofx using kscript?

Tags: maven, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

Im trying to compile `Kotlin` with `tornadofx` using `kscript`

But I don't know which is the correct dependency for `javafx` and `tornadofx`

when I Compile appears the next error:

```
[kscript] Resolving dependencies...Failed to lookup dependencies. Maven reported the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project maven_template: Could not resolve dependencies for project kscript:maven_template:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.8.0_20 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/../lib/ant-javafx.jar -> [Help 1]
```

this is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env kscript
@file:DependsOn("no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.17")
@file:DependsOn("com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3")

import tornadofx.*
import javafx.*
vbox {
    button("Button 1").setOnAction {
        println("Button 1 Pressed")
    }
    button("Button 2").setOnAction {
        println("Button 2 Pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you would post your pom.xml

Comment: hi sorry but this command "kscript" no use xml files , works only with a text file that i post .

Comment: Sorry then, I assumed it uses maven as build system because of the tag

Comment: I don't think tornadofx is compatible yet with Java 9/10, check out there GitHub page - https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx#tornadofx